# Overlay is forcing page to go to start whenever it is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have to used many overlay so
when i close the overlay either right or left my page moves up and comes from start.
it can be easily checked by open the last two overlay.

this is the code.
i dont know where is mistake. or what should i add more in css.
as i selected the position fixed , may be this is the error but if changed it than more errors occur.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

left side overlay

```
$("#left-click1").click(function(){
 $("#image").prop("src","C:/Users/Ahsan/Documents/sublime/nature1.jpg");
 $("#para").text("1111ABCD");
});

$("#left-click2").click(function(){
 $("#image").prop("src","C:/Users/Ahsan/Documents/sublime/nature2.jpg");
 $("#para").text("2222ABCDEF");
});
```

right side overlay

```
    $("#right-click1").click(function(){
     $("#image1").prop("src","C:/Users/Ahsan/Documents/sublime/nature3.jpg");
     $("#para1").text("3333ABCDEF");
    });

    $("#right-click2").click(function(){
      $("#image1").prop("src","C:/Users/Ahsan/Documents/sublime/nature4.jpg");
      $("#para1").text("4444ABCDEF");
    });

    $("#right-click3").click(function(){
      $("#image1").prop("src","C:/Users/Ahsan/Documents/sublime/nature5.jpg");
      $("#para1").text("4444ABCDEF");
    });

    function openAnimeleft(){
     document.getElementById("left").style.width = "60%";
}

function closeAnimeleft(){
     document.getElementById("left").style.width = "0";
}
```

right side animation

```
function openAnimeright(){
    document.getElementById("right").style.width = "60%";
}

function closeAnimeright(){
    document.getElementById("right").style.width = "0";
}

<div id="left" class="left-styles">
<a href="#" class="cross-button" onclick="closeAnimeleft()">&times;</a> 
<div>
<div>
  <img id="image">
</div>
<div>
  <p id="para"></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

left side animation div

```
<div id="mains"><p>00000001</p>
<span id="left-click1" onclick="openAnimeleft()"> &#187;&#187; left-open1</span>
</div>

<div id="mains"><p>00000002</p>
<span id="left-click2" onclick="openAnimeleft()"> &#187;&#187; left-open2</span>
</div>
```

right side animation div

```
<div id="right" class="right-styles">
    <a href="#" class="cross-button" onclick="closeAnimeright()">&times;</a>
<div>
<div>
<img id="image1">
</div>
<div>
<p id="para1"></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="mains"><p>00000003</p>
<span id="right-click1" onclick="openAnimeright()">&#171;&#171; right-open1</span>
</div>

<div id="mains"><p>00000004</p>
<span id="right-click2" onclick="openAnimeright()">&#171;&#171; right-open2</span>
</div>

<div id="mains">
<p>00000005</p>
<span id="right-click3" onclick="openAnimeright()">&#171;&#171; right-open3</span>
</div>
```

css code

```
.left-styles {

    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111000;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.left-styles a ,.right-styles a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    transition: 1s;
}

#right-click1,#right-click2,#right-click3,#left-click1,#left-click2{
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer; 
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px)
{

    .left-styles {padding-top: 15px;}
    .left-styles a {font-size: 18px;}
    .right-styles {padding-top: 15px;}
    .right-styles a {font-size: 18px;}
}
.right-styles {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #111000;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}
.right-styles .cross-button, .left-styles .cross-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.right-styles a:hover, .left-styles a:hover{
    color: green;
}

#para,#para1{
    color: green;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 5vw;

}

#image,#image1{
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vh;
    margin-left: 6%;
}

#left,#right{
    overflow: scroll;
}

#mains{
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle/plnkr to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, when you click the close button the page jumps to the top of the scroll window. If that is the problem, you need to use `event.preventDefault();`. This will stop the `a` tag behaving like a link.

```
$("#left-click1").click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 $("#image").prop("src","C:/Users/Ahsan/Documents/sublime/nature1.jpg");
 $("#para").text("1111ABCD");
});
```